# Magento: how to add a static block AFTER product list

Tags: static-block

In a web site my boss wants me to insert a static block AFTER the product list of that category. Up to now, using the Magento front end application, the one you can see [here](http://bradfrost.com/blog/web/magento-static-blocks/), I have seen that I can add a static block only before the product list. How can I do to put the block after the product list for each category? 
For example [this](http://collaudo.casaarredostudio.it/tavoli-consolle-allungabili.html) is a page of the site I am working on and I would like to display the block at the bottom of the page, after the product list but before the footer links.
I think I should change some files (like page.xml or local.xml) ma I don't know how and I haven't found anything useful in the net. Can you help?

Comment: Reposting a question won't fix. You can still respond to comments in the original question you posted

Comment: I was going to close and delete my first question which is mal formed and put this which explains better the problm...

Comment: then just edit your question